# Different raster's resolution but same pixel number, how is it possible?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ndvi, landsat, resolution, multi-band

Bands 1-7 & 9 of Landsat 8 have a spatial resolution of 30 meters, but Band 10 and 11 have 100 meters. Bellow there are NDVI and Band 10 Rasters of a study area.

Does each pixel of the band 10 represent a 100x100 meters area?

Does each pixel of NDVI raster represent a 30x30 meters area?

I am asking because those 2 images have the same number of pixels and it seems strange to me.

How can a 100x100 meters resolution be the same as a 30x30 meters resolution?

**Image 1: Band 10 (100x100 meters resolution)**

[image]

**Image 2: NDVI Raster (30x30 meters resolution)**

[image]

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 100m resolution is the resolution of the Band10 sensor.

To make it possible to process data easily across all bands, the images uses 30m pixel size whatever the bands' sensor resolution.

If you look closely at your Band10 image, you'll notice the 100m squares, resampled to 30m pixels

[See this for reference](https://landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/satellites/landsat-8/)